# How do I find the Taylor series of f(x) = 5cos(x), a = 11pi????

Tags: taylor-expansion

I started the problem but I am confused how to set up.

```
f(x) = 5cos(x)          f(11pi) = -5
f'(x) = -5sin(x)        f'(11pi) = 0
f''(x) = -5cos(x)       f''(11pi) = -5
f'''(x) = 5sin(x)       f'''(11pi) = 0
f''''(x) = 5cos(x)      f''''(11pi) = -5
```

Taylor Series Begins as
$$-5 + 0\cdot(x-11\pi) + \frac{5(x-11\pi)^2}{2!} + \frac{0\cdot(x-11\pi)^3}{3!} +\frac{-5(x-11\pi)^4}{4!} + \dots$$

I so far wrote it down as

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  {(-1)^{n+1}}  \frac{(x-11\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I am suppose too have the 5 in there too but I have no idea how to include that, would somebody please be able to show me how to put the 5 into my answer???

Comment: Can you not just multiply the whole series by 5? I'm not fully understanding

Comment: You **have** a factor of 5 already in your expression "Taylor series begins as ...", it's just that you haven't included that one in the expression with the $\sum$ notation.

Answer (score 1):

$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  {(-1)^{n+1}}  \frac{5}{(2n)!} (x-11\pi)^{2n}$$

This is the final and correct answer hopefully

Comment: yes, that's right

Answer (score 0):

By $x=11\pi+y$ we have

$$5\cos(x)=5\cos (11\pi+y)=5\cos (\pi+y)=-5\cos(y)$$

then use the usual expansion for $\cos y$ at $y=0$ and then substitute $y=x-11\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea in such cases to write $x=a+h=11\pi+h$, then to transfer the expansion around $a$ (in the variable $x$) to an expansion around $0$ (in the "better" variable $h$), and here it is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x)
&= 5\cos(x)
\\
&=5\cos(11\pi+h)=5\cos(\pi+h)
\\
&=5\cos\pi\cdot\cos h-\dots=-5\cos h
\\
&=-5\left(\frac 1{0!}-\frac 1{2!}h^2+\frac 1{4!}h^4-\frac 1{6!}h^6+\dots
\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
and now it is time to insert back $x-11\pi$ instead of $h$.